# OneToMany and ManToOne annotations

Tags: hibernate, annotations

In ManyToOne mapping which column will act as foreign key: which column from address table is used as foreign key in Student table

```
public class Student {
    private String studentName;
    private Address studentAddress;

public Student(String studentName, Address studentAddress) {
        this.studentName = studentName;
        this.studentAddress = studentAddress;
    }
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Address getStudentAddress() {
        return this.studentAddress;
    }
```

and the address class is :

```
 public class Address {

    private long addressId;
        private String street;

            @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "ADDRESS_ID")
        public long getAddressId() {
            return this.addressId;
        }
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS_STREET", nullable = false, length = 250)
        public String getStreet() {
            return this.street;
        }
    }
```

as in ManyToOne this is done by @JoinColumn and @JoinColumn

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "STUDENT_PHONE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "STUDENT_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PHONE_ID") })
public Set<Phone> getStudentPhoneNumbers() {
return this.studentPhoneNumbers;
}
```

Does I am missing something, or this is correct and I dont understand correclty

Comment: What's your question exactly? Why don't you test if everything works and ask if you have a problem?

Comment: @JB...thanks for the reply.. ..yes i have executed it and it works fine...but my question is how it works automatically in manyToOne without any annotation of type JoinColumn or JoinTable.....

Answer (score 0):

It works without specifying JoinColumn or JoinTable because the JPA specification defines default mappings in case these annotations are not present:

> 2.10.3.2 Unidirectional ManyToOne Relationships
>
> The following mapping defaults apply:
>
> Entity A is mapped to a table named A.
>
> Entity B is mapped to a table named B.
>
> Table A contains a foreign key to table B. The foreign key column name
>   is formed as the concatenation of the following: the name of the
>   relationship property or field of entity A; "_"; the name of the
>   primary key column in table B.
>
> The foreign key column has the same type as the primary key of table
>   B.